Evaluation of $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\prod^{n}_{r=1}(\tan^{-1}(r))^{\frac{1}{n}}$
Evaluation of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\prod^{n}_{r=1}(\tan^{-1}(r))^{\frac{1}{n}}$.
What I tried: Let $ L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\prod^{n}_{r=1}(\tan^{-1}(r))^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Then $\ln(L)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{1}{n}\ln(\tan^{-1}(r)).$
I tried to convert it into Reimann sum, but here it is not in the form of  $\tan^{-1}(\frac{r}{n})$ form. How can I calculate further?

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{r=1}^n\ln\arctan r-\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\ln\arctan r\right)=\ln\frac\pi2$, by Stolz-Cesaro $\ln L=\ln\frac\pi2$.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cesàro_summation

Using the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula
$$\sum^{n}_{r=1}\ln\left(\tan^{-1}(r)\right)=n\ln\frac\pi2-\frac{\ln n}\pi+O(1)$$

Consider the following theorem:

Theorem. Let $\{x_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $x\in\mathbb{R}$. If
$$\lim_{j\to\infty}x_j=x,$$
then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nx_j=x.$$

For a proof of this, see for example here. For your problem we can then notice that
$$\lim_{r\to\infty}\ln(\arctan r)=\ln\frac{\pi}{2},$$
from which it follows that
$$\ln L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^n\ln(\arctan r)=\ln\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
Thus
$$L=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
